# How the response times of the application can be customised in Gatling report?

Tags: gatling

Our application demands performance to be analysed at a granular level to capture 5 responses rather than default 3 responses in the graph reports.

Noticed that, we have below configuration in config. file

```
lowerBound = 800 # Lower bound for the requests' response time to track in the reports and the console summary
higherBound = 1200 # Higher bound for the requests'
```

is there any ways we can increase the capture of number of response times?

Answer (score 0):

Easy and simple answer: no, not atm.